# Import structure from Matlab into Mathematica 12 and nested lookup

Tags: import, data-structures, searching, data-format

I use Matlab and generate data that I save in a structure in a MAT file. I want the results to be loaded into Mathematica, as several analysis and plots are best when done in the latter than in the former.

For example, in Matlab I generate the structure that contains different "a" and "b" fields, and "b" it's itself a structure that contains two fields "m" and "n":

```
Struct.a   = [1,2,3];                      %Vector data
Struct.b.m = [1,2,3;4,5,6];                %Matrix data
Struct.b.n = {'Name 1','Name 2','Name 3'}; %String cell array
```

I save this structure in a MAT file called "Struct.mat".

When I use the **Import** command in Mathematica 12:

```
P=Import["Struct.mat","MAT"];
```

I obtain P as the array of nested lookups:

```
{{{<|a->{{1.,2.,3.}},b->{{<|m->{{1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.}},n->{{{Name 1},{Name 2},{Name 3}}}|>}}|>}}}
```

My question is: Is it possible to extract each field separately into another variable, without nesting lookups? For example, I use

```
M=Lookup[Lookup[P[[1, 1, 1]], "b"][[1, 1]], "m"]
```

to extract Struct.b.m into variable M; and I would like to use something like

```
M=Lookup[P,"b.m"]
```

PD. The data I obtain from Matlab has a lot of fields and nested fields, and those contain matrices with hundreds of rows and columns, string arrays and anonymous functions. This is a simplified example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Your `P` has reproduced your `Structs` as `Association`s but embedded them in some frustrating brackets.

Someone probably has a simple way to use `Flatten` to extract just the nested `Association`s.

Still likely worthwhile to work through what have so you can have an idea of what to do with it all.

Formatting it like the following may help you see what you have:

```
p = {{{<|
      a -> {{1., 2., 3.}},
      b -> {{<|
          m -> {
            {1., 2., 3.},
            {4., 5., 6.}
            },
          n -> {{{Name 1}, {Name 2}, {Name 3}}}
          |>}}
      |>}}};
```

Examining p:

```
Dimensions[p]
{1, 1, 1}
```

Taking the most embedded list:

```
p[[1, 1, 1]]

<|
 a -> {{1., 2., 3.}}, 
 b -> {{<|
     m -> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}, 
     n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}|>}}|>
```

which starts looking more like a proper `Association`.

Assign a variable to the above:

```
p2 = p[[1, 1, 1]]
```

Now you can start to access the data:

```
p2[a]
{{1., 2., 3.}}

p2[b]
{{<|m -> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}, 
    n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}|>}}
```

Hmmm....too many brackets on `p2[b]` so,

```
p2[b][[1, 1]]

<|m -> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}, 
 n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}|>
```

Set a variable to the above just to make it easier to see:

```
p3 = p2[b][[1, 1]]
```

Then...

```
p3[m]
{{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}
```

and

```
p3[10]
{{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}
```

First thoughts...

What you want to get to from your example:

```
p = <|
  a -> {{1., 2., 3.}},
  b -> <|
    m -> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}},
    n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}
    |>
  |>
```

Then you can access the data in a way analogous to how you would in a `Struct`:

```
p[a]
{{1., 2., 3.}}

p[b]
<|m -> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}, 
 n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}|>

p[b][m]
{{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}

p[b][10]
{{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}
```

More to come later...

---

So you can work something like the following into your code to import your Struct data:

```
p = {{{<|
      a -> {{1., 2., 3.}},
      b -> {{<|
          m -> {
            {1., 2., 3.},
            {4., 5., 6.}
            },
          n -> {{{Name 1}, {Name 2}, {Name 3}}}
          |>}}
      |>}}};

p = Flatten[p][[1]];
p[b] = Flatten[p[b]][[1]];
p
```

Which gives you:

```
<|
 a -> {{1.`, 2.`, 3.`}},
 b -> <|
   m -> {{1.`, 2.`, 3.`}, {4.`, 5.`, 6.`}},
   n -> {{{Name}, {2 Name}, {3 Name}}}|>|>
```

A well formed `Association` that you can readily access.